# Regular expression for string like :"Iphone 6"

Tags: regex, automata

I'm working on an NLP project.

I want to match a string that have the form :
"Iphone 6, Iphone 5, Iphone 4, etc." to become a phrase , not separated words like :"Iphone" and "6".

Here is my regular expression that I can conduct until now:

```
^iphone $\+[+]?([0-9]*)?[0-9]+([\.,]\d+)*
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/gN8hI0/1 ?

Comment: Great , thanks a lot for your help @AlexK.

Comment: @AlexK. how about a regex for Iphone 6s , iphone 5s , etc?

Comment: `(\bIphone \d+s?\b)` to match them all, remove the `?` to match just ones ending in `s`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex like this:

```
[iI]phone [456]
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zW5fN2/1)**

If you want to support any number you can use `\d+` instead of `[456]`

Update: since you added a new case for your comment: *Iphone 6s , iphone 5s*. Then you can add `s?` to the pattern:

```
[iI]phone [456]s?
```

And if you want to contemplate Iphone 6s and 6se, then you can have:

```
[iI]phone [456](?:se?)?
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, how about a regex for Iphone 6s , iphone 5s , etc?

Comment: @xtiger, you didn't specified that in your question. Anyway, you could use this regex for that purpose `[iI]phone [456]s?`